# PostgreSql Pass an array of strings as an argument to a function

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating a function that gets two arrays, one of integers and one of strings then creates a materialized view, naming it with a concatenation of these parameters. In this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reports_mt_views(
    accounts integer[],
    namesa text[])
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   i integer;       
BEGIN        
FOREACH i IN ARRAY accounts
    LOOP 
    EXECUTE 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW pps.order_reports_materialized_' || accounts[i] || '_' || namesa[i] || ' AS
...
```

However when I launch the function as follows:

```
SELECT reports_mt_views(ARRAY [1,9,504231,505674], '{''a'',''b'',''c'',''d''}');
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'a'"
LINE 1: ...TE MATERIALIZED VIEW pps.order_reports_materialized_1_'a'
```

It happens because the simple quotes that I'm sending. Otherwise I can not send the array of strings, if I do so:

```
SELECT reports_mt_views(ARRAY [1,9,504231,505674], {'a','b','c','d'}, 3);

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: ...T pps.reports_mt_views(ARRAY [1,9,504231,505674], {'a','b','...
                                                               ^
```

I can not send and read the array of *strings* to generate the name of the materialized view.